# picture srcset with webp - how to implement sizes?

Tags: html, webp, srcset

I'm trying to have a picture tag with WebP support.

( load image-full if the screensize is over 1024px, image-1024 for max-width 1024px, image-768 for max-width 768 px and image-500 for max-width 500px )

I've got this code, and w3 validator is complaining that: When the srcset attribute has any image candidate string with a width descriptor, the sizes attribute must also be present.

How do I implement sizes into this? Is there a better/different way I should do this?

```
<picture>
// load webp in different sizes if browser supports it
<source media="(min-width: 1025px)" 
    srcset="webp/image-full.webp"
    type="image/webp">
<source media="(max-width: 1024px)"
    srcset="webp/image-1024.webp" 
    type="image/webp">
<source media="(max-width: 768px)" 
    srcset="webp/image-768.webp"
    type="image/webp">
<source media="(max-width: 500px)" 
    srcset="webp/image-500.webp"
    type="image/webp">

// load jpg in different sizes if browser doesn't support webp
<source media="(min-width: 1025px)"
    srcset="siteimages/image-full.jpg" 
    type="image/jpeg">
<source media="(max-width: 1024px)"
    srcset="siteimages/image-1024.jpg" 
    type="image/jpeg">
<source media="(max-width: 768px)"
    srcset="siteimages/image-768.jpg" 
    type="image/jpeg">
<source media="(max-width: 500px)"
    srcset="siteimages/image-500.jpg" 
    type="image/jpeg">

// fallback in different sizes, as well as regular src.
<img 
    srcset="siteimages/image-1024.jpg, 
        siteimages/image-768.jpg,
        siteimages/image-500.jpg"

    src="siteimages/image-full.jpg" 

    alt="image description"
    class="myimageclass">
</picture>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While providing multiple `srcset` in `img` tag browser needs both `scrset` and `sizes` attribute to help the browser pick the right one.

You can add update code like below and it should work without complaints -

```
<picture>
// load webp in different sizes if browser supports it
<source media="(min-width: 1025px)" 
    srcset="webp/image-full.webp"
    type="image/webp">
<source media="(max-width: 1024px)"
    srcset="webp/image-1024.webp" 
    type="image/webp">
<source media="(max-width: 768px)" 
    srcset="webp/image-768.webp"
    type="image/webp">
<source media="(max-width: 500px)" 
    srcset="webp/image-500.webp"
    type="image/webp">

// load jpg in different sizes if browser doesn't support webp
<source media="(min-width: 1025px)"
    srcset="siteimages/image-full.jpg" 
    type="image/jpeg">
<source media="(max-width: 1024px)"
    srcset="siteimages/image-1024.jpg" 
    type="image/jpeg">
<source media="(max-width: 768px)"
    srcset="siteimages/image-768.jpg" 
    type="image/jpeg">
<source media="(max-width: 500px)"
    srcset="siteimages/image-500.jpg" 
    type="image/jpeg">

// fallback in different sizes, as well as regular src.
<img 
    srcset="siteimages/image-1024.jpg 1024w, 
        siteimages/image-768.jpg 768w,
        siteimages/image-500.jpg 500w"

    sizes="(max-width: 1024px) 1024px,
            (max-width: 768px) 768px,
            (max-width: 500px) 500px"

    src="siteimages/image-full.jpg" 

    alt="image description"
    class="myimageclass">
</picture>
```

In short we are telling browser to load the image referenced in the srcset list that most closely matches the chosen slot size

[Responsive Images Detailed Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images)

Comment: Thank you! Works great. I wasn't sure where to add it, several tutorials added a 800w or a 2x somewhere inside the source tag too. 
In the example you linked to it's not clear to me what <img  sizes="(max-width: 600px) 480px,800px"> does? 
For a max-width screensize of 600px, it's serving ..both the 480px and the 800px size images?

Comment: No problem.For a max-width screensize of 600px it will pick 480px image and 800px image for rest of screensizes.

Comment: funny if I can't really write a set into the srcset attribute of source, or could I?

Comment: you also have to reverse the sources order from the smallest to the biggest to make it work, as i tested on Firefox

Comment: The sizes attribute here has its pieces in the wrong order. The first match is used, so for a small screen, say 400px, it'll match max-width: 1024px first and so load the largest image, where surely you want it to load the smallest.

Answer (score 8):

Building on @varun's answer, you can simplify the code a bit:

- improvement: `image/jpeg` not needed if it's already in `<img>` - browsers fall back automatically
- improvement: combine multiple `<source>` tags.
- fix: add default width of `100vw` to `sizes` tag (i.e. viewports wider than 1024px not defined)
- fix: `media` tag is for art direction, not for resolution switching, see [Mozilla's guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images) on the difference

```html
<picture>
    // load webp in different sizes if browser supports it
    <source type="image/webp"
        sizes=" (max-width: 500px) 500px,
                (max-width: 768px) 768px,
                (max-width: 1024px) 1024px,
                100vw"
        srcset="
          webp/image-500.webp 500w,
          webp/image-768.webp 768w,
          webp/image-1024.webp 1024w,
          webp/image-full.webp 1920w
        "
        >
    // fallback on original src.
    <img 
        srcset="siteimages/image-1024.jpg 1024w, 
            siteimages/image-768.jpg 768w,
            siteimages/image-500.jpg 500w"
        sizes=" (max-width: 500px) 500px,
                (max-width: 768px) 768px,
                (max-width: 1024px) 1024px,
                100vw"
        src="siteimages/image-full.jpg" 

        alt="image description"
        class="myimageclass">
</picture>
```

Comment: Your sizes attribute is in the wrong order. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images which says that the browser will choose from the srcset based on the first matching element of sizes. That means in your case with a 400px viewport, the `(max-width: 1024px)` will match and it'll load a needlessly large image. It should be smallest through to largest, then the fallback.

Comment: Thanks @tremby, good catch.

Comment: @Tim 1) Thanks for providing this much more structured & readable way! I will go with this one as my code template. 2) Style hint: Please be more explicit in such a comment, e.g. "Thanks tremby, good catch. Corrected my code snippet accordingly. B/c "Good catch" is certainly a respectful reaction to your fellow feedback-giver but only standing by itself leaves other readers uncertain whether that feedback was integrated in the above answer or not. Every reader then needs to check this by him/her-self to reassert oneself. Thanks.